# JavaScript For Loop Skipping items in an Array

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html-lists, auto-increment, for-in-loop

I'm a little confused on what is happening here. I have an html unordered list and I am to sort it out into 3 separate lists based on an attribute value. This is very basic, I'm aware but I ran into something peculiar with a for loop and its increment.

```
[this is code provided to be worked with]
 <ul id="queue">
        <li want="coffee">Phil(html)</li>
        <li want="coffee">Sandy(html)</li>
        <li want="sandwich">Enrique(html)</li>
        <li want="coffee">Joe(html)</li>
        <li want="muffin">Alex(html)</li>
        <li want="chili">Zoe(html)</li>
        <li want="sandwich">Bahamut(html)</li>
        <li want="timbits">Rydia(html)</li>     
    </ul>
```

Then sort it out into these lists

```
[this is code provided to be worked with]
<section id="sandwiches">
        <h1>Sandwich line</h1>
        <ul id="sandwich-line">
        </ul>
    </section>


    <section id="coffee">
        <h1>Coffee line</h1>
        <ul id="coffee-line">
        </ul>
    </section>


    <section id="everything-else">
        <h1>Everythin else line</h1>
        <ul id="everything-else-line">
        </ul>
    </section>
```

I currently have this

```
        ///////////////////////////////////
        // HTML Queue
        ///////////////////////////////////

        // Grab the Queue element and 
        var ulList = document.getElementById('queue').getElementsByTagName('li');

        for(var i = 0; i < ulList.length;){
            // this finds out what they "want" based on the attribute
            var ulOrder = ulList[i].getAttribute("want");

            // To organize the line we can use if statements
            if (ulOrder === "coffee"){
                coffeeLine.appendChild(ulList[i]);

            } else if (ulOrder === "sandwich"){
                sandLine.appendChild(ulList[i]);
            } else {
                elseLine.appendChild(ulList[i]);
               }
           }
```

[Which works!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brc9R.png)

But when I change my for loop to add increments (Like I have always been doing)

```
 for (var i = 0; i < ulList.length; i++){
```

I end up with something like this

[Does Not Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1bqJ.png)

Now I've also tried using

```
for (var i in ulList) {
```

and I get the same results as it not working

Can anyone help me understand what I am obviously missing?
Thank you!

Comment: Off topic: `want` isn't a valid HTML attribute. Consider using `data-want`.

Comment: I think the case might be that you change the amount of variables in your list. Could it be that elements are removed from the ulList when you use the appendChild()-function? Try to console.log() it

Comment: @bvx89 That's the case (+ `getElementsByTagName` returns a live NodeList/HTMLCollection), why not convert your comment to an answer?

Comment: Because it was only a theory, not an answer

Comment: @bvx89 It _is_  an answer : ).

Comment: each iteration ulList.length get evaluated, so in i++ variation you end up your i < ulList.length too fast, in a second variation the loop is stopped too fast cause it'st not been re-evaluated and your array shrinks you get to the end of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've probably noticed, [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) *moves* the element to a new position in a document. [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) returns an array-like object, which is live, i.e. it is automatically updated when you add or remove elements to/from its "scope".

You can fix your loop by decrementing `i` by one every time you append from `ulList`.

Comment: Swet, ok, so because I am removing something out not adding i++ works because my position of 0 never changes but my list keeps getting smaller until there is no list?

Comment: Correct. That's why your first version works. i < arr.length; when arr is of length 0 gives false.

Comment: In your case, yes. Another way is to read `ulList[0]` on every iteration, but this can be done only, if every item from the list is really removed. (Basicly this is what you've done in the snippet which has worked).